# Qt Tab rename when double clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

i am using visual Studio with Qt.
i do not have access to Qt designer. its all done through coding (C++);

i have an opensource software called easypaint.

i got stuck at trying to rename tabs. I want to be able to rename tabs when user double clicks on the tab itself.

i created a new function to filter the doubleClick event :

```
 bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
 `enter code here`{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {
         return true;
     } else {
         // standard event processing
         return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
     }
 }
```

then i added this line to a function that initializes the TabWidget:

```
installEventFilter(mTabWidget);
```

can anyone please guide me through this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Qt doesn't allow an inline editor to open on the tab's name.  So you'd most likely have to create and run a very small QDialog to query for the new name:

```
 bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
 {
    if (obj == mTabWidget &&
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {

        // query and set tab(s) names
        QTabWidget *tab = qobject_cast<QTabWidget *>(obj);
        if(tab)
        {
            QDialog dlg;
            QVBoxLayout la(&dlg);
            QLineEdit ed;
            la.addWidget(&ed);
            QDialogButtonBox bb(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
            la.addWidget(&bb);
            dlg.setLayout(&la);
            if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
            {
                tab->setTabText(0, ed.text());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

It might be that Qt's dynamic memory management doesn't like the local class instances, so you'd have to convert all those class instances created to pointers created with `new`, but then please don't forget to tell the QDialog to delete on close or call `dlg->deleteLater()` after you queried the new name.

Another way to solve this via a fake inline editor would need a bit more work:

- create a QLineEdit
- move it right above the tab's, bring it up front and set keyboard focus to it
- wire signals and slots

  - pressing enter should use the contents of the QLineEdit
  - leaving focus from the line edit should be treated as "abort" and delete the line editor
- implement the slots to do what's needed.

Comment: void MainWindow::initializeTabWidget()
{
    mTabWidget = new QTabWidget();
    mTabWidget->setUsesScrollButtons(true);
    mTabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
    mTabWidget->setMovable(true);
    connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(activateTab(int)));
    connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(enableActions(int)));
    connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));
 
 installEventFilter(mTabWidget); 

    setCentralWidget(mTabWidget);
}

 how can i connect your function ? is installeventfilter(QObject) ?

Comment: should i add a installeventfilter in the above functions ? @St0fF

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be used as an event filter, as the function's name already suggests :)

Comment: it works nicely, the only problem i have is connecting the buttons. OK and Cancel wont respond to mouse click

Comment: well, you tried to connect() them?  Anyhow, this might be a problem as I described: Qt relies a lot on dynamically allocated Objects - so it might work better if you created a small class derived from QDialog.  On the other hand it might just be that the QDialogButtonBox's CTor simply needs a QDialog instance pointer to correctly connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the event filter in the fallowing way:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
     if (obj == mTabWidget &&
         event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {

         QTabWidget *tab = qobject_cast<QTabWidget *>(obj);
         // Set tab(s) names         
         tab->setTabText(0, "New Name");
     }

     // Standard event processing
     return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
 }
```